# Passing data from Html.Action to the partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I'm still relatively new to MVC 3. I need to pass data from my @Html.Action methods through the controller to a partial view.

So here is my flow.

I'll call @Html.Action like this:

```
@Html.Action("SidebarMain", "Home", new List<int>(new int[] {1, 2, 3}))
```

Then it will hit my Controller. Here is my method in my Home Controller:

```
public ActionResult SidebarMain(List<int> items)
{
    return View(items);
}
```

Then my Partial View should be able to access the data like so:

```
@model List<int>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SidebarMain";
    Layout = null;
}

<div>
@foreach (int item in Model)
{
    <div>@item</div>
}
</div>
```

BUT: I'm getting a null exception for the Model, meaning It's not passing through.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
Html.Action("SidebarMain", "Home", new { items = new List<int>(new int[] {1, 2, 3}) })
```

And put a breakpoint in your SidebarMain Action to see, if you are getting `items`

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** your code is missing the **items** parameter name in the `Html.Action()`.
Other than that the code should be functional.

```
Html.Action("SidebarMain", "Home", new {items = new List<int>(new int[] {1, 2, 3}) })
```

As a suggested practice, i would use a dedicated `ViewModel` in my view rather than just sending the array of integers. Because, in this way of a clean `ViewModel` - a container of your properties that you display in the view, your code may add other properties later on, as our code always evolves.

Reference to the usage of a ViewModel concept: [**Exercise 5: Creating a View Model**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3fundamentals_topic7.aspx)

Comment: Just to clarify, by ViewModel you mean a model that the view is strongly typed on correct?

Comment: yes you are right, that point is tried to be clarified/mentioned in my second paragraph.

Comment: Wow thank you.  I didn't realize the parameter name had to be the same in the view as in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Good answer from DarthVader.  Are you returning this as Ajax?  If you are embedding it in a main view, you should really return it as a PartialView with

```
return PartialView("SidebarMain", model);
```

This is where SidebarMain is the name of the partial view that you are returning.  Try this in combination with what DarthVader suggested and make sure that you're getting a model to pass back to the view.

After posting, I realized that you are using Html.Action.  If this is a true sidebar, it SHOULD be loaded with ajax as a partial view and you should be calling

```
Ajax.ActionLink("SidebarMain", "Home", new { items = new List<int>(new int[] {1, 2, 3}) })
```

This will allow you stay on your current page.  If you aren't looking for ajax functionality, I apologize for the rabbit trail :)

Answer (score 0):

DarthVader's suggestion may have worked. This is what I ended up doing:

1) Removed the controller

2) Called it like this:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("SidebarMain", new int[] {1,3,4,2});}
```

3) Here is my view code:

```
@model int[]
@foreach( int item in Model){
...
```